# Netty - Different pipelines for different occasions?

Tags: java, netty

I want to create a client/server system where I can send objects and commands to the server. I already found out how to send objects (json) and how to use an echo server.

However, the echo example only had one type of message, namely one string, being used. How do I implement a system where I have different kind of messages for different occasions?

Edit: Having read more about handlers and pipelines, I can now  ask more precisly what I need: Is it possible to add more than one pipeline to a server or do I have to create a new server with a new port for every use case?

Comment: You can have different pipelines for each channel.  You can also manipulate each pipeline dynamically.

Comment: How? What is the key word I have to look for?

Comment: The pipeline is initialized by a ChannelInitializer.  If you create your own you can add some logic to set the pipeline up like you need.  Any time after that you can use the context to get the pipeline and add/remove any handlers you want.

Answer (score 5):

It is currently not supported to add more then one ChannelPipeline. We plan to support "nested" pipelines at some point but not sure when exactly. For now you could modify the pipeline on the fly to meet your needs.

Check out the PortUnification example which does the same:
https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/portunification/PortUnificationServerHandler.java

Comment: Well, I want to create an application that runs on a server and that can be used by clients. They should be able to send commands and get corresponding responses and sometimes get notifications. The only way I see netty being able to do this is using one port for every possible command. Do you know a framework that is capable of doing this?

Comment: Why don you encode the command "ID" at the head of the message. Let's say the first int represents the command. Then, when you receive a message, read the first int, figure out what the command is, then swap in the corresponding handler for that command.

Comment: Checkout for example the memcached binary protocol which allows all kind of different commands on the same port. Basically it encodes everything in the "header". http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/MemcacheBinaryProtocol